# Le plus proche + COI

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, superlatifs

J'ai un doute sur une phrase, mais je ne sais pas pourquoi je la sens mieux d'une manière que d'une autre.

J'aimerais exprimer le fait que je souhaite placer un objet près d'une cible. Pour cela est-ce qu'il est plus correct de dire :

> Le plus proche possible de la cible

Ou

> Le plus proche de la cible possible

Answer (score 3):

> Le plus proche possible de la cible

*Possible* est rattaché à proche, on ne peut pas aller plus près de la cible.

> Le plus proche de la cible possible

Rattaché à cible : cela sous entend que parmi les cibles, il est *possible* de se rapprocher d'une d'entre elles. S'il n'y a qu'une cible, utiliser la première phrase.

Answer (score 2):

*Possible* est un adjectif variable sauf lorsqu'il est précédé d'un  superlatif singulier ou pluriel comme *le(s) plus*, *le(s) moins*, *le(s) mieux*, *le(s) pire(s)*, *le(s) meilleur(s)*. Ainsi, on écrira « les sites possibles » et « le plus de sites possible ».

Le plus correct est de dire : « Le plus proche possible de la cible. »

Answer (score 0):

> Le plus proche possible de la cible

Il y a une seule cible et il s'agit de s'en approcher au plus près. (possible est rattaché à proche)

> Le plus proche de la cible possible

Il y a plusieurs cibles, une seule "possible", et il faut s'en approcher. (possible est rattaché à cible. Dans ce cas, on choisirait plutôt le terme "cible potentielle", "cible probable", etc.)